# Trigger play function on scroll once

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, scroll, mp3

I want to play a sound when scrolled to the defined id #counter. It works fine but I want to play it once. When somebody scrolls up or down again the music is in a kind of loop. How to stop that?

```js
// play countdown sound on scroll when you hit #counter 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var elemTop = $('#counter').offset().top, 
            elemHeight = $('#counter').outerHeight(), 
            windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var countdownSound = new Audio('./music/countdown.mp3');

    if( windowScroll > (elemTop + elemHeight - windowHeight) ) {
        countdownSound.play();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe: `$(window).off('scroll')`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could just put an external variable to check:

```
var played = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var elemTop = $('#counter').offset().top, 
  elemHeight = $('#counter').outerHeight(), 
  windowHeight = $(window).height(),
  windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var countdownSound = new Audio('./music/countdown.mp3');

  if( windowScroll > (elemTop + elemHeight - windowHeight) && played == false) {
    countdownSound.play();
    played = true;
  }
});
```

or, you maybe could build a play function and call it via lodash.once (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#once), or something like that.

---

That said, often when calling functions onscroll, it's useful to throttle them:

```
$(window).scroll(_.throttle(do_things_onscroll, 25));

function do_things_onscroll(){
//[do things]
}
```

Note that I'm still taking advantage of Lodash utilities, but you could use some other library like underscore or just find out the code to only throttle.

Comment: The first solution worked. I think the simplest the better. Anyway I'll need to test it and see if I can take advantage of other functionality to add to the function. Thanks.

Comment: Essencially, once() is only (maybe) a more elegant way of doing the same, while throttle() saves memory/cpu during scroll. It allows for less function calls during scroll, at regular intervals. It's almost always a better solution, just like debounce() onresize. If you've got some spare time, take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/